# Deploying an SWT application on Java Webstart

Tags: swt, jnlp, java-web-start

Is it possible to deploy SWT applications using JNLP. Especially loading the swt native library (dll in Windows, so in Linux)? Any links? I found one at [IBM Developer Works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-jws/), however it just describes using swt.jar. In addition to that, is it possible to load the native dll files over JNLP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM developer works article you linked to contains everything you need to know including how to load the native dll files.

Notice the nativelib element in the resources. The jar file referred to here will contain any native libraries required by the application. See [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) for an explanation of using nativelib.